# Copy Paste on Latex

Tags: copy-paste

I can not copy and paste text from Latex itself, nor from nowhere else.
I have shecked the hotkeys and they do not inclue CRTL + C nor CRTL + V.
Could you please help ? thank you !!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Which editor are you using? That is, what is the name of the program you open when you want to write a LaTeX document?

Comment: You need to give some more information, or supply us with a crystal ball:) What operating system? What editor? What programs?  Is it latex specific or is it all programs?

Comment: We should give the OP time to respond before closing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like OP encountered some editor problem. It has been six days and the problem shall be solved, considering that OP gave no more information.